# Cross Domain iframe auto height using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

When I write this function in iframe with cross domain, I got 'permission denine document'. This function is working well in same domain.

```
function changeHeight(iframe)
{   

try
    {
        //var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;     
        if (innerDoc.body.offsetHeight) 
        {
            iframe.height = innerDoc.body.offsetHeight + 32; //Extra height FireFox
        }
        else if (iframe.Document && iframe.Document.body.scrollHeight) //ie5+ syntax
        {
            iframe.height = iframe.Document.body.scrollHeight;
        }       
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question actually?

Comment: can anyone help me out telling me that what is the benefits of using javascript instead of using jquery?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal jQuery is not magic. jQuery **is** JavaScript. So all things you can do in jQuery can be done in JS (usually with longer code), but with JS you can do things which are impossible in jQuery. How is you comment related to the question? Did you think jQuery can bypass same-origin policy?

Comment: get the height from js running inside the frame, then `top.postMessage()` the dimensions to the framing page via a `message` event.